# Make black screen in proteus?

Tags: proteus

Could you tell me how I can make the black screen like this in proteus so that it look like more interesting simulation :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the **template** menu and change the colors in design defaults, graphic styles and textr styles.

For example the background color can be changed using the paper color property

[image]

There is a way to copy the color scheme from a project to your working project. To do so open your project and then select **template -> load styles from design** and browse to the project from which you want to copy the color scheme (in your case the \samples\Interactive Simulation\Animated Circuits\diode09.dsn)